# Obtener un list de datos atraves de un endpoint con RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un endpoint que da una serie de datos y querria meterlos en un list pero no se como, he encotnrado para metértelos en un objeto. alguna idea?

```
    @Override
public List<DatosNasa> obtenerDatos(String codigoTecnico, String dni) {
    List<DatosNasa> datos = new ArrayList<>();
    final String uri = "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2020-09-09&end_date=2020-09-16&api_key=DEMO_KEY";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    DatosNasa result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, DatosNasa.class);
}
```

Comment: Pero el servicio solo regresa un objeto igual lo quieres poner en una lista? SSI es asi, lo agregas : `datos.add(result);`

Comment: Lo mejor seria que muestres un ejemplo de objeto Json que te retorna, porque si el objeto que retorna es un List no te debería funcionar colocar un Objeto.

Comment: Revisando el Json que retorna el servicio no necesitas una Lista, si te explicas mejor porque necesitas guardar la respuesta en una lista, o si es otro servicio el que estas consultado o cual es tu error.

Comment: ESTE ES EL link del Json https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2020-09-09&end_date=2020-09-16&api_key=DEMO_KEY y necesito una lista xq son varios objetos no uno

Comment: Por favor detalla cuáles son los datos que necesitas de la respuesta de la API. No queda claro

Comment: Para vitar confusiones lo mejor es que coloque el código del objeto DatosNasa

Answer (score 1):

Lo que devuelve la API de la nasa es un objeto JSON, no una lista.

> Tengo un endpoint que da una serie de datos y querria meterlos en un list pero no se como

Supongo que te refieres a que quieres obtener ciertos datos dentro de la respuesta.

La respuesta que se obtiene de la url que pasaste es, resumidamente, la siguiente:

```json
{
   "links":{},
   "element_count":178,
   "near_earth_objects":{
      "2020-09-16":[
         {/*datos varios*/},
         {/*datos varios*/}
      ],
      "2020-09-09":[
         {/*datos varios*/}
      ]
   }
}
```

Como se puede ver en el ejemplo de arriba, el objeto JSON tiene una propiedad `near_earth_objects` que es un objeto en sí. Y cada key del objeto es una fecha, el valor de cada key es un arreglo con datos que presumo son los que necesitas para tu aplicación.